# Move X to the other side.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this little equation here. The purpose of it is to solve for $X$ where it is the value needed to be added to $Z$ then that sum reduced by a percentage, $Y$, in order to get back to the original number, $Z$. I hope that's understandable.

$$Y(Z + X) = Z$$

I want to isolate $X$ and move it to the other side of the equation. Is something like this possible?

Usage example:

$$Y = 0.25,
Z = 100$$

When solving for $X$ you get $33.33$.

Comment: What are $X$, $Y$, and $Z$? numbers or matrices? if matrices, have you tried you example with a $2 \times 2$ matrix?

Comment: @user2943324:  the example suggests they are real numbers

Comment: But the question is classified as linear algebra

Comment: @user2943324:  some users think linear algebra is algebra with linear equations

Comment: @Ross Millikan Oh!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
Distribute the left side, getting $YZ+YX$
Subtract $YZ$ from each side, isolating the term with $X$ (the thing you want to solve for)
Divide by $Y$

In your example, I get $0.25(100+33.33)\approx 33.33\neq 100$
Given $Y=\frac 14, Z=100$, I get $X=300$

Comment: Okay, thanks. I made some arithmetic errors originally. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Why distribute $Y$ first? You should divide by $Y$ first, then just subtract $Z$.

Comment: @Dan:  that works, too.  When started I was solving for $Z$, but then realized I was supposed to solve for $X$.